# USB mouse is not working for Ubuntu 14.04 after updating

Tags: 14.04, updates, mouse

Everything was going fine but after updating my system by

```
sudo apt-get update
```

My USB mouse is not working like before. I tried on various port and other bluetooth mouse too but still the result is the same.

NB: My touchpad is working fine and laptop model is ASUS i7.

Comment: `sudo apt-get update` does nothing but syncing the remote repo package names with local one..it has absolutely no impact on any other part of the system let alone _updating_ the system..

Comment: but what can be the possible problem? it was working fine but suddenly not :(

Comment: Start by checking the relevant logs e.g. `/var/log/syslog` and `/var/log/kern.log` ..also just to be sure check if those mice are not faulty..

Comment: no, the same mouse is working in the other pc eg. windows 7

Comment: this one helped me : http://askubuntu.com/questions/506673/usb-mouse-not-working-after-unplug-plug-in-14-04?rq=1

Comment: Cool. If you want you can also put an answer how was the issue resolved so that future readers can take help from that..

Comment: I have solved the problem from here  : http://askubuntu.com/a/743481/332166

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, I have solved my problem with this solution : 
 https://askubuntu.com/a/743481/332166

> > This happens because the power management switches off usb devices in order to save power after a certain period of inactivity. Although there are solutions to solve this manually I recommend to install software called tlp.

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linrunner/tlp
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install tlp
$ sudo tlp start
```