# USB mouse stopped working ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, usb, mouse

My USB mouse used to work fine on Ubuntu 16.04, but recently it stopped working. I have a dual booting with Windows, and the mouse works fine there.
So, for troubleshooting, I tried this solution from this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/506673/usb-mouse-not-working-after-unplug-plug-in-14-04/743481#743481).

But when I typed `sudo rmmod usbhid` on the terminal, this error is shown,

> rmmod: ERROR: Module usbhid is not currently loaded.

So, how do i proceed from here onwards?